# Configure Nginx reverse proxy with Mosquitto

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, mqtt, nginx-reverse-proxy, mosquitto

Hello I came from this post [Configure Nginx reverse proxy for MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71379937/configure-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-mqtt)

I have a virtual machine, in this virtual machine I have nginx proxy listening to the port 1885 where the clients connect, and I want to make it redistribute the messages among all the Mosquitto containers (In this example I delete the other two containers I have) this to create a mosquitto volume

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "1885:1885"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-conf/_data/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - backend

  mosquitto1:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    ports:
      - "1886:1886"
    environment:
      - listener=1886:1886
      - allow_anonymous=true
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto.conf:/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Then I have the nginx.conf

```
events {
}

http {
    upstream mosquitto_backend {
        
    zone tcp_mem 64k;
    proxy_protocol on;
    }

    server {
        listen 1885;
        server_name localhost;
    log_format mqtt '$remote_addr [$time_local] $protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time "$request" "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$upstream_addr"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mqtt_access.log mqtt;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mqtt_error.log; # Health check notifications
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://mosquitto_backend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem I have is despite being able to suscribe to the port 1885 I cannot write messages from other terminal or connect using mqtt explorer

running docker-compose up will return this where it tries to use port 1883 and clashes with something

```
docker-compose up --remove-orphans
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container data-mosquitto1-1  Created                                                                                                                          0.1s
 ⠿ Container data-nginx-1       Created                                                                                                                          0.0s
Attaching to data-mosquitto1-1, data-nginx-1
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: Error: Address not available
data-mosquitto1-1  | 1678977906: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
data-nginx-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
data-nginx-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
data-nginx-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
data-nginx-1       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: IPv6 listen already enabled
data-nginx-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
data-nginx-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
data-nginx-1       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
data-nginx-1       | 2023/03/16 14:45:06 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
data-nginx-1       | 2023/03/16 14:45:06 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.3
data-nginx-1       | 2023/03/16 14:45:06 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
data-nginx-1       | 2023/03/16 14:45:06 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 3.10.0-1160.83.1.el7.x86_64
data-nginx-1       | 2023/03/16 14:45:06 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
data-nginx-1       | 2023/03/16 14:45:06 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
data-nginx-1       | 2023/03/16 14:45:06 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
```

I used lsof -i:1883 and netstat -tuln to see if this port is being used but is not being used

I know I'm using an image eclipse-mosquitto and this image shall have the port 1883 and despite changing later it access to it and no problem if that's the case, but what I don't know what else is accessing to it making the conflict.

Could you help me please?

**EDIT**

I made some changes and i'm able to suscribe to the port 1885 and in other terminal i can publish messages in the same port but the user suscribed can only see half of the messages

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "1885:1885"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-conf/_data:/etc/nginx
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto1
      - mosquitto2
    networks:
      - backend

  mosquitto1:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto1
    ports:
      - "1886:1883"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/docker-compose-conf/_data/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config    
  mosquitto2:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto2
    ports:
      - "1887:1883"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/docker-compose-conf/_data/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

my nginx.conf

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}


stream {

        log_format mqtt '$remote_addr [$time_local] $protocol $status $bytes_received ' 
                '$bytes_sent $upstream_addr';
    
    upstream mqtt_cluster {
        server 192.168.210.36:1886; #mosquitto1 | 192.168.210.35
        server 192.168.210.36:1887; #mosquitto2 | 192.168.210.39
    }


    server {
        listen 1885;
        proxy_pass mqtt_cluster;
       

        access_log /var/log/nginx/mqtt_access.log mqtt;
        
    }
}
```

and my mosquitto.conf

```
# =================================================================
# Default listener
# =================================================================

# Port to use for the default listener.
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
```

all containers are up and the load balancer is working propertly because it deliver the message to the containers in port 1886 and 1887

I suscribed to them also and can see the messages.

Everytime I publish in the port 1885 the messages delivered to the port 1886 are not printed in port 1885, so in order to see one message I have to execute the publish command twice.

it's like the configuration of the container in the port 1887 is overlapping the port 1886.

I also try leaving only one container and all messages are delivered to the suscriber in port 1885.

Could you tell me if I have something wrong in my docker-composer.yml file please?

Comment: The edit should have been a new question (but point 4 in my answer covers why this is happening)

Comment: Thank you for answering again, i'm checking your answer but are you sure that's for my case?

I mean the port 1885 is the load balancer in nginx and the mosquitto brokers are on port 1886 and 1887, i don't want those ports to comunicate among them, the clients will conect to port 1885 so only that have to know all data, the other two port will have only what the balancer sends to them.

Comment: It doesn't work that way, NGINX doesn't understand MQTT, it will distribute clients in a round robin fashion between the 2 brokers, so a client subscribed will only see messages published by clients that happen to end up connected to the same broker by nginx, which is likely to change each time it connects (e.g. EVERY time you run `mosquitto_pub` it has a 50/50 chance of being on the same broker). If you want to get all messages then you need to bridge the 2 brokers so they share messages.

Comment: and could you tell me how to bridge the brokers please, I created a mosquitto.conf for each broker pointing each other but this creates an infinite loop?

Now I have two brokers but the idea is to increase them.

Comment: Go read the (very good) mosquitto docs, have a go, then if you have a problem ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

A few of problems with what you are trying

1. You have mounted the `mosquitto.conf` on the wrong path. The config file should be mounted in `/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` not `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`. See the entry on Docker hub for details https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto
2. The `environment` section is not doing anything useful, those values need to be included in the `mosquitto.conf`
3. You can NOT use HTTP proxying with native MQTT, there are just totally different protocols. You can configure Nginx in stream proxy mode which will work. You could configure mosquitto to support MQTT over WebSockets (again you will need to supply a configuration file to enable this) which will work with a HTTP proxy, but does rely on all your clients also supporting MQTT over WebSockets and being specifically configured to use it.
4. Unless you configure bridging between the multiple MQTT brokers then this set up isn't going to work. Since without bridging messages published to one broker will not end up being delivered to any clients connected to the other 2 brokers. (A shared volume between the mosquitto containers will not share any messages)

Comment: Thank you so much for reply.
What I'm trying to  achieve here is to have multiple dockers in a virtual machine, that's why I added the enviroment section, because the volume mosquitto1 shall point to the port 1886 and the next volume Mosquitto2 has to point to the port 1887.

i'm very noob at this, so your help it's very appreciated.

Comment: If you are using a proxy infront of the mosquitto instances, they can all run on the same port (as they will be in separate container instances with their own IP stacks)