# Setting up EMQX behing nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, mqtt, reverse-proxy, emqx

I'm trying to setup emqx mqtt broker behind an nginx reverse proxy, unfortunately without success.

I'm using the following configuration.

**nginx.conf**

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


stream {
  upstream stream_backend {
     server  127.0.0.1:1883 weight=1;
  }

  server {
      listen 8080;
      #proxy_send_timeout 2h;
      #proxy_read_timeout 2h;
      proxy_connect_timeout 150s;
      proxy_timeout 150s;
      proxy_pass stream_backend;
      proxy_buffer_size 3M;
      tcp_nodelay on;
      #proxy_protocol on;
  }
}
```

**emqx.conf**

```
node {
  name = "emqx@127.0.0.1"
  cookie = "mysecret"
  data_dir = "data"
}

listeners.tcp.default {
  bind = "127.0.0.1:1883"
  proxy_protocol = true
  proxy_protocol_timeout = 30
  enable_authn = false
}


dashboard {
    listeners.http {
        bind = 18083
    }
}
```

nginx and emqx are running within the same docker compose file.

Trying to connect is giving the following error

[image]

> emqx            | 2023-09-26T23:20:47.213039+00:00 [error] supervisor:
> 'esockd_connection_sup - <0.2858.0>', errorContext:
> connection_shutdown, reason: {invalid_proxy_info,<<"GET /mqtt
> HTTP/1.1\r\n">>}, offender:
> [{pid,<0.3309.0>},{name,connection},{mfargs,{emqx_connection,start_link,[#{enable_authn
> => false,limiter => undefined,listener => {tcp,default},zone => default}]}}]

### Update

Updating the emqx.conf to run native mqtt solved the mqtt connection problem

```
node {
  name = "emqx@127.0.0.1"
  cookie = "mysecret"
  data_dir = "data"
}

listeners.tcp.default {
  bind = "127.0.0.1:1883"
}


dashboard {
    listeners.http {
        bind = 18083
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your intention to connect via websockets (as per the test connection screenshot) or native MQTT (as per the emqx config)? (see [here](https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/v5.0/configuration/listener.html#configure-tcp-listener) vs [here](https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/v5.0/configuration/listener.html#configure-websocket-listener)). Nginx can proxy either (but will not convert) - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71380504/11810946) may help.

Comment: My intention is actually to run native mqtt and a rest api over the same port 8080. According to your link I managed to fix the problem for mqtt. I will update the post.

Comment: "run native mqtt and a rest api over the same port 8080" - that's going to be tricky. To do that nginx would need to pre-read some of the incoming data and determine if it's HTTP or MQTT so it can forward appropriately (I don't think there is out-of-the-box functionality to do this). It would be possible if you use TLS (using SNI or ALPN to direct the connection appropriately). If you use MQTT over websockets then its simple to share the port (because they are both HTTP based).

Comment: Well I even need location directives :) I tried the round robin aproach,which is probably not a reliable solution. `upstream mqtt {     server  127.0.0.1:1883 weight=1 ;     server 127.0.0.1:8081 weight=2 ;     server 172.21.36.12:443 weight=3 ;  }`
Is there any big performance loss when running mqtt over websocket?

Comment: There is a handshake to establish a websocket connection (can be fairly small  - see example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers)) and then a few bytes per message. Note that not all clients support websocket connections.